# Provided Schema does not match Table on append

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a big select with joins where both tables are the same size, so in order to process it I limit the select on the right table to chunks (by using %) and then run the same select several times, one for each chunk and append to a destination table.

The process works fine for chunks 0,1,2 but for any subsequent chunk it fails and claims 'Provided Schema does not match Table'.

Some of the failing jobs are the following:

```
job_01eb892ab77c49f2ab5a7d24fa19ea96 (chunk 3)
job_ae450380bacd42b8aae7b7b350a8bd61 (chunk 4)
job_6f40617d0e6046e7b474dffef220ade7 (chunk 5)
job_edfbf86b95364efba3a21ae855827eb4 (chunk 6)
```

If I delete the table and run the first failed chunk (3) in isolation (job_bbbd3c8b56594725a3d3933c79f96286), it works fine and the schema in the new table is the same and as expected.

If I selectively process chunks 0,1,3,4, chunk 3 works fine and now it fails on 4 (job_76c3addb316644f595988cbc393ffa8a), if I run chunks 2,3,4,5 it fails on chunk 5 (job_c5d99e0fa6b0481b8e5ea6b5d6f26271).

This looks like an issue at BQ is preventing to append the forth chunk (whichever it is) to the destination table and it gives an incorrect description of the error.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug where when we start writing the table results to disk we do so with a subtly different schema format. I've checked in a fix, but it likely won't be available until next week's release.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, if you let me know when the fix is in place, then I will test this for you. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known bug with query results returning unpredictable field modes (required vs optional). IIRC you can play games with AS or IF() to force the optional flag to be set.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how the field modes are set when the table is created, but I have an AS for each field and for those fileds that could be null I have an IFNULL(), so I'm not sure whether the field modes could be the cause, as the results should be stable. Thanks